# Delete mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-delete

My current issue is as follows.
The below select script works perfectly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM orderheader, orderbody, orderbodylocation
WHERE orderheader.DateCreated > '2011-02-01 00:00:00' 
AND orderheader.OrderID = orderbody.OrderID 
AND orderbody.OrderBodyID = orderbodylocation.OrderBodyID 
AND orderbody.OrderID = orderbodylocation.OrderID 
AND orderheader.Status <= 1
```

but the below delete query which is a duplication of the where clauses fails around the dateCreated clause.

```
DELETE 
FROM orderheader, orderbody, orderbodylocation
WHERE orderheader.DateCreated > '2011-02-01 00:00:00' 
AND orderheader.OrderID = orderbody.OrderID 
AND orderbody.OrderBodyID = orderbodylocation.OrderBodyID 
AND orderbody.OrderID = orderbodylocation.OrderID 
AND orderheader.Status <= 1
```

the DateCreated field within orderheader table is a DATETIME type.

I'm trying to delete every order newer then 1-2-2011 (d-m-y) along with the orderheaders associated table data in orderbody and orderbodylocation tables.

I've run out of ideas and I haven't had much experience with mysql DateTime datatype fields.
If anyone can see my error it would be greatly appreciated if you could let me know what I've done wrong.

Comment: [offtop]It is the wonderful case when foreign keys constraint with delete cascade is a great tool to use[/offtop]

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE orderheader.DateCreated > '2011-02-01 00:00:00' AND orderheader.OrderID ' at line 3

Comment: @roguecoder: what mysql version do you run this on?

Comment: @zerkms: mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $

Comment: @roguecoder: 1) it was not even released, you're using development unstable version 2) it it were released - it would be may of 2005, and today is 2011. I strongly recomment you to update to 5.0.91

Comment: i installed the latest version of wamp and thats what it came with lol!

Comment: @roguecoder: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ --- are you sure? `Mysql 5.1.53 (version 64 bits); Mysql 5.5.8 (version 32 bits)`

Comment: @zerkms: wait i think i pulled the version number form the wrong area. Server version: 5.1.36-community-log does that sound beter ?

Comment: @roguecoder: sure it is. But now I haven't any ideas about why you experience such error. I don't see any error.

Comment: @roguecoder: The only way I can think of such error for such delete query is that you have some invalid invisible char right before where (between from tables and where clause), so what if you remove all new lines and spaces between `orderbodylocation` and `WHERE` and put one space (not newline) again?

Comment: @zerkms: lol ok. well thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @roguecoder: your irony is understandable, but this could be a possible issue ;-)

Comment: nope nothing there that shouldnt be there

Comment: @zerkms: that thanks anyway was in response to the i don't see any errors comment. :) i do appreciate the help by the way. no sarcasm here. i removed all spaces and put them back in and removed new lines. nothing seems to work and i'm sure i have done this once or twice before for uni a few years back

Answer (score 1):

If the manual page to which zerkms have courteously posted a link applies to your version of MySQL, then you simply need to add (once again) the table(s) you want to delete from to the `DELETE` instruction. You need to put them between `DELETE` and `FROM`, like this:

```
DELETE table1, table2, ... /* probably some or all tables in the FROM list */
FROM orderheader, orderbody, orderbodylocation
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the error message would be helpful!

I don't know mysql but if it's like other SQLs you cannot reference multiple tables in the FROM clause of a DELETE command.

If you have foreign keys with the cascade delete property then just do a delete for the header rows and the rest will be automatically deleted.

If you don't have cascade delete set up for the related tables then you will need to do 3 
delete statements, deleting data from the bottom up.  For the lower-level tables you will need to use a sub-select to match against the header table.  Here's an example for the order body:

DELETE FROM orderbody where orderbody.OrderID in (select orderHeader.OrderID
FROM orderheader WHERE orderheader.DateCreated > '2011-02-01 00:00:00' 
AND orderheader.Status <= 1)

HTH

Leo